# Do I need to free popup menus in GTK?

Tags: c, gtk

This is the first time I'm using GTK. I have the following code and I'm wondering if it is leaking memory. It's inside a function that is called every time a right click happens.

```
GtkWidget *menu = gtk_menu_new();

//while loop adding a bunch of menu items
gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu), menu_item);

gtk_widget_show_all(menu);
gtk_menu_popup(GTK_MENU(menu), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 3, event->button.time);
```

Is the cleaning handled automatically by GTK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GtkMenu`, as seen in your code, is a subclass of `GtkWidget`, which in turn is a subclass of `GInitiallyUnowned`. So it has all that floating-ref magic around.

When you popup a menu, it works just like `GtkWindow`, so it automatically ref-sinks the floating reference, and eventually, when the menu is dismissed, it is unreferenced and freed.

Short answer: Yes, it is automatic, so your code is correct.

You can check if I'm right with this code:

```
g_object_ref_sink(menu); //ref = 1
g_menu_popup(...);
g_print("I am %s\n", menu->ref_count==1? "right" : "wrong");
g_object_unref(menu);
```

Note: do not use `ref_count` for anything but debugging! It should be considered an implementation detail of `GObject` and never be accessed directly.